# huge difference between du and df results' on NFS

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs

I know there are several topics about "du and df", but mine seems different to me.

Below, as you can see, usage ration of my NFS mount is %53 with 106 GB.

```
[root@myhost imp_test]# df -kh
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                                 32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                    32G  856K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                    32G  433M   31G   2% /run
tmpfs                                                    32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                                                80G  4.5G   76G   6% /
/dev/sdc                                                 40G  475M   40G   2% /var/log
NFS Mount                                               200G  106G   94G  53% /usr/imp_test
tmpfs                                                   6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/65215
```

Yet, usage in reality is completely different(I shortened file' s names and all these files are PostgreSQL dump files generated using pg_dump). I want to point out "myfiles_x" and "myfiles_y" files.

```
[root@myhost imp_test]# cd /usr/imp_test
[root@myhost imp_test]# du -sh *
17G     myfiles
25G     myfiles
12G     myfiles
4.3G    myfiles
23M     myfiles
62G     myfiles_x
62G     myfiles_y
7.8G    myfiles
```

Only these files are capturing 124 GB. From the all other questions I know the results of du and df cannot be match, but on all of them(as far as I checked) usage ratio on the result of "df" are higher then "du" s output. Approximately, sum of the "du" s output is 190GB and it is 2 times of "df" result.

By the way, "myfiles_x" and "myfiles_y" are exactly the same files but different name and there is no symbolic link between them.

How it is possible or am I missing something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157116/94566) answer, you may have a case with your shell expanding the symlinks.

Summary:

> `*` is a shell glob; it is expanded by the shell before running any command.

You may want to use `find` ahead of `du` (as bash shell doesn't give you the option to not expand the symlinks).

`find` example:

```
find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name myfiles* -exec du -sh {} +
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to type "no". There is no symbolic link between any of them.